# What is the correct VBA syntax for Refresh method of QueryTables object?

Tags: macos, vba, excel

This Excel for Mac code downloads a table of stock data from Yahoo and inserts it into a worksheet labeled "DataSheet". It gets the ticker, start and end date from the worksheet "QuerySheet".

This code fails on the .Refresh method of the QueryTable object and I do not understand why. What is the correct syntax?

```
Sub data_get()

Dim ticker As String, sday, smonth, syear, eday, emonth, eyear As Long
Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet

Set QuerySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("QuerySheet")
Set DataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet")


DataSheet.Columns("A:G").ClearContents

With QuerySheet

  ticker = Range("A2")

  sday = Day(Range("G2"))
  smonth = Month(Range("G2"))
  syear = Year(Range("G2"))

  eday = Day(Range("H2"))
  emonth = Month(Range("H2"))
  eyear = Year(Range("H2"))


End With


With DataSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ticker & "&d=" & emonth & "&e=" & eday & "&f=" & eyear & "&g=d&a=" & smonth & "&b=" & sday & "&c=" & syear & "&ignore=.csv" _
    , Destination:=DataSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "table1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    '.PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    '.RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    '.TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    '.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    '.BackgroundQuery = True


    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False    <---- 1004 Error
    '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: That looks right, at least for the Windows version. What happens if you leave out the `Backgroundquery` parameter?

Comment: It doesn´t work to pull in the data. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn´t, I´ve been looking at it so long that I can´t tell which direction to go in.

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong here is that the code is adding a new connection to your workbook each time it is run (unless you delete the connection elsewhere already). WHat you should be doing instead is either just refresh the querytable (if the filename stays the same) or change the Connection property so it has the new url and then call the refresh method.